# Spring startup issue - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must only contain valid chars

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

After adding Spring Cloud(Finchley.M8) dependency to Spring Boot(2.0.6.RELEASE) project, got an exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must only contain valid chars
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:583)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must only contain valid chars
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId.<init>(EndpointId.java:44)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId.of(EndpointId.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer$EndpointBean.<init>(EndpointDiscoverer.java:471)
```

Comment: In my case , use `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` instead of   
 `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include="*"`

Answer (score 2):

I had same exception while starting springCloudConfigServer project.

Root cause was incorrect value for the below property in application.properties (Typo mistake)

Before:
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=**bus=refresh**

I changed it like below and my project started successfully
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=**bus-refresh**

Answer (score 1):

For Me also Getting same Problem. Reason for me is in **application.yml** file I used **/** symbol for **endpoint**.[image]

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: hystrix.stream
```

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation time, it appears that I should use a different version of Spring Cloud.

I changed from **Finchley.M8** to **Finchley.SR2** and everything starts working fine.

Spring Cloud + Spring Boot 2.0.x compatibility notes:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/spring-cloud-finchley-release-notes

Comment: Yup, generally you should use release versions as opposed to milestones